# Select xml tags from nvarchar datatype column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data sample is below. This data is saved in a Nvarchar datatype column of table named XMLDATA.

```xml
<interactions>
<interaction index="0" id="3-2-1-10-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:49:26" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction>
<interaction index="1" id="3-2-1-20-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:17" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction>
<interaction index="2" id="3-2-1-30-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:21" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction>
</interactions>
```

The tables looks like

```html
ID  Interactions
46020960    <interactions><interaction index="0" id="3-2-1-10-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:49:26" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="1" id="3-2-1-20-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:17" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="2" id="3-2-1-30-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:21" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="3" id="3-2-1-40-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:25" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="4" id="3-2-1-50-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:29" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="5" id="3-2-1-60-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:32" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="6" id="3-2-1-70-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:35" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="7" id="3-2-1-80-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:39" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="8" id="3-2-1-90-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:42" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="9" id="3-2-1-100-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:45" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="10" id="3-2-1-110-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:49" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="11" id="3-2-1-120-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:53" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="12" id="3-2-1-130-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:56" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="13" id="3-2-1-140-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:59" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="14" id="3-2-1-150-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:03" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="15" id="3-2-1-160-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:06" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="5" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="16" id="3-2-1-170-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:10" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="17" id="3-2-1-180-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:14" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="18" id="3-2-1-190-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:17" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="9" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="19" id="3-2-1-200-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:21" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="9" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="20" id="3-2-1-210-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:23" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="9" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="21" id="3-2-1-220-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:26" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="9" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="22" id="3-2-1-230-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:29" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="23" id="3-2-1-240-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:33" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="24" id="3-3-1-20-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:50" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="25" id="3-3-1-40-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:52:56" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="5" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="26" id="3-3-1-60-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:53:00" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="9" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="27" id="3-3-1-80-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:53:06" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="6" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="28" id="3-3-1-100-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:53:12" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="9" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="29" id="3-3-1-120-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:53:39" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="9" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="30" id="3-3-1-140-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:53:44" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="7" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="31" id="3-3-1-160-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:53:51" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="32" id="3-3-1-180-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:53:55" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="7" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="33" id="3-3-1-200-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:54:01" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="3" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="34" id="3-3-1-220-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:54:07" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="3" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="35" id="3-3-1-240-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:54:12" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="7" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="36" id="3-3-1-260-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:54:17" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="7" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="37" id="3-3-1-280-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:54:22" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="9" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="38" id="3-3-1-300-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:54:26" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="39" id="3-3-1-320-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:54:33" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="40" id="3-3-1-340-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:54:37" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="9" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="41" id="3-3-1-360-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:54:44" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="42" id="3-3-1-380-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:54:49" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="9" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="43" id="3-3-1-400-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:55:04" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="44" id="3-3-1-420-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:55:08" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="45" id="3-3-1-460-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:55:15" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="7" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="46" id="3-3-1-480-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:55:21" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="8" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="47" id="3-3-1-440-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:56:58" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="6" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction></interactions>
46111758    <interactions><interaction index="0" id="3-2-1-10-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:09:28" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="1" id="3-2-1-20-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:09:33" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="2" id="3-2-1-30-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:09:37" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="3" id="3-2-1-40-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:09:41" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="4" id="3-2-1-50-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:09:45" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="5" id="3-2-1-60-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:09:48" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="6" id="3-2-1-70-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:09:52" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="7" id="3-2-1-80-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:09:55" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="8" id="3-2-1-90-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:09:59" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="9" id="3-2-1-100-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:10:02" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="10" id="3-2-1-110-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:10:07" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="11" id="3-2-1-120-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:10:11" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="12" id="3-2-1-130-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:10:15" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="13" id="3-2-1-140-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:10:18" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="14" id="3-2-1-150-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:10:25" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="15" id="3-2-1-160-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:10:29" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="16" id="3-2-1-170-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:10:59" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="17" id="3-2-1-180-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:02" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="18" id="3-2-1-190-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:07" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="19" id="3-2-1-200-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:10" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="20" id="3-2-1-210-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:13" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="21" id="3-2-1-220-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:17" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="22" id="3-2-1-230-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:21" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="23" id="3-2-1-240-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:24" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="24" id="3-3-1-20-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:36" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="25" id="3-3-1-40-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:41" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="26" id="3-3-1-60-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:46" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="27" id="3-3-1-80-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:53" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="28" id="3-3-1-100-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:11:57" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="29" id="3-3-1-120-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:04" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="30" id="3-3-1-140-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:09" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="31" id="3-3-1-160-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:15" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="32" id="3-3-1-180-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:19" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="33" id="3-3-1-200-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:22" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="34" id="3-3-1-220-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:26" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="35" id="3-3-1-240-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:31" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="36" id="3-3-1-260-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:34" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="37" id="3-3-1-280-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:39" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="38" id="3-3-1-300-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:42" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="39" id="3-3-1-320-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:48" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="40" id="3-3-1-340-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:52" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="41" id="3-3-1-360-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:12:58" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="42" id="3-3-1-380-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:13:02" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="43" id="3-3-1-400-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:13:06" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="44" id="3-3-1-420-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:13:10" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="45" id="3-3-1-440-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:13:15" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="46" id="3-3-1-460-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:13:19" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction><interaction index="47" id="3-3-1-480-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T19:13:25" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction></interactions>
```

My requirement is to get the 'id' and 'learner_response' only in a select query.
I have tried below but its not working for me. Its only giving blanks.

```
select a.Id,
x.y.value('(/interactions/interaction/id/node())[2]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Q_id,
x.y.value('(/interactions/interaction/learner_response/node())[7]', 'nvarchar(255)') as Response
from (select  Convert(XML, Interactions) as XML, ID from xmldata) As A
Cross Apply xml.nodes('//Attributes/learner_response') As x(y)
```

I need the data like :

```html
ID              Q_ID    Response
46020960    3-2-1-40-10 10
46111758    3-2-1-40-10 10
46096320    3-2-1-40-10 7
46028650    3-2-1-40-10 null
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: I have removed the images. Is it better now?
I am unable to add more code as the character limit :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify *which* interaction you want for each ID, but this query will return them all, and you can filter after if necessary.

```
create table xmldata(id int, interactions nvarchar(max))
insert into xmldata(id, interactions) values (46020960,'
<interactions>
<interaction index="0" id="3-2-1-10-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:49:26" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction>
<interaction index="1" id="3-2-1-20-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:17" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction>
<interaction index="2" id="3-2-1-30-10" timestamp="2022-04-27T16:51:21" weighting="NULL" type="numeric" latency="NULL" learner_response="10" result="correct" description="NULL"><objectives/><corr_resps/></interaction>
</interactions>')

go

with x as (select id, cast(interactions as xml) doc from xmldata) 
select x.ID, 
       d.i.value('@index','int') response_index,
       d.i.value('@id','varchar(20)') q_id, 
       d.i.value('@learner_response','int') learner_response
from x
cross apply x.doc.nodes('/interactions/interaction') d(i)
```

Comment: Can you please also help me to know how to join this with other tables to get the final result with added columns from other tables as well?

Comment: It would just be a JOIN.